# KeyListener not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

For some reason, my KeyListener just isn't responding to KeyPressed events.

If it matters, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. It should be printing "Key Pressed" whenever a key is pressed, but it doesn't.

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class DisplayPanel extends JPanel
{
    private Tile[][] tiles;
    private Creature[] creatures;
    private Dungeon dungeon;
    private Player player;

    public DisplayPanel(Dungeon dungeon, Tile[][] tiles, Creature[] creatures, Player player)
    {
        this.tiles = tiles;
        this.creatures = creatures;
        this.dungeon = dungeon;
        this.player = player;
        addKeyListener(new DungeonKeyListener());
        requestFocus();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        int maximum = (getWidth() < getHeight()) ? getWidth() : getHeight();
        for (Tile[] row : tiles)
        {
            for (Tile tile : row)
            {
                if (tile != null && tile instanceof Tile)
                {
                    tile.draw(g, maximum/tiles.length, maximum/tiles[0].length);
                }
            }
        }
        for (Creature creature : creatures)
        {
            if (creature != null && creature instanceof Creature)
            {
                creature.draw(g, maximum/tiles.length, maximum/tiles[0].length);
            }
        }

        if (player != null && player instanceof Player)
        {
            player.draw(g, maximum/tiles.length, maximum/tiles[0].length);
        }
    }

    private class DungeonKeyListener extends KeyAdapter
    {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Key pressed!");
            dungeon.press(e.getKeyCode());
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your panel have the focus? Have you tried to add the KeyListener to the root window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Call `super.paintComponent` (not related to you question, but will solve some issues later on)
- Make the component "focusable" - [`Component#setFocusable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable%28boolean%29)
- Use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener`
- Use `Component#requestFocusInWindow` over `Component#requestFocus`...

From the Java Docs

> Because the focus behavior of this method is platform-dependent,
>   developers are strongly encouraged to use requestFocusInWindow when
>   possible

Comment: Cheers. In regards to the third point, we have to use KeyListeners for homework :/

Comment: `paintComponent` is a link in the paint chain.  The super version does important work to keep the UI in a consistent state.  Unless you're willing to take over it's responsibility, you should call `super.paintComponent`

Comment: Also, super.paintComponent() throws: ```DisplayPanel.java:25: paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics) in javax.swing.JComponent cannot be applied to ()
  super.paintComponent();
       ^
```

Comment: Don't forget to pass the graphics reference ;) `super.paintComponent(g)`