# KeyListener wont focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, keylistener

I'm new to Java so please forgive me asking for help, but after 4 hours of searching for a solution I'm really getting desperate.

I'm currently setting up a game and want to implement key controls. I tried to do this via `KeyListener` and `KeyEventDispatcher` but I just can't get it to work.
The `KeyListener` just won't react. I think that the method that is supposed to use it has the focus.

Here's the code:

```
public class Sins extends JFrame implements KeyEventDispatcher  {

 public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
     if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED ) {
         if(KeyEvent.VK_UP == e.getID()){
             System.exit(0); 
         }

     } else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
           if(KeyEvent.VK_UP == e.getID()){
             System.exit(0); 
           }
     } else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
           if(KeyEvent.VK_UP == e.getID()){
             System.exit(0); 
           }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

and here is the method where it is supposed to be working at:

```
  public void run() { 

  setFocusable(true);   
  backgroundGraphics = (Graphics2D) background.getGraphics();
  long fpsWait = (long) (1.0 / 30 * 1000);



requestFocusInWindow();

main: while (isRunning==true) {
    long renderStart = System.nanoTime();

    KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
    manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(this);

    x++;
    requestFocusInWindow();

    // Update Graphics
    do {
        Graphics2D bg = getBuffer();

        if (isRunning == false) {
            break main;
        }
        renderGame(backgroundGraphics); // this calls your draw method

        if (scale != 1) {
            bg.drawImage(background, 0, 0, width * scale, height
                    * scale, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        } else {
            bg.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        }
        bg.dispose();

        requestFocusInWindow();


        this.requestFocus();

        if(x ==5000){
            isRunning=false;
        }

    } while (!updateScreen());

    // Better do some FPS limiting here
    long renderTime = (System.nanoTime() - renderStart) / 10000;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, fpsWait - renderTime));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.interrupted();
        break;
    }


    renderTime = (System.nanoTime() - renderStart) / 10000;

   }

   this.dispose();
   System.exit(0);
}
```

The program is currently closing itself after counting up to 5000. For test purposes I'm trying to close it via the up button but it just won't close that way.
I would really appreciate some help, as I said I'm new to Java.

Comment: Not sure how you even get this to compile. E.g. I have no idea what `main:` is supposed to be doing in your code.

Comment: Well, if isRunning =false its supposed to "stop" the methode by breaking, im planing to use this later on to stop the game.

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy Its a label. Think of it like a goto, then understand why you shouldn't know about it ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's ironic I literally just figured that out while trying to figure out ways to double-break from a nested loop. Never knew such a thing existed in Java, probably for the exact reason you pointed out :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [KeyListener not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354230/keylistener-not-working)

Comment: `background.getGraphics();`  This is the wrong way to go about painting `Graphics`.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you were facing with `KeyListener` is a well know and well documented (here on SO especially). `KeyListener` will only on respond if the component they are attached to is focusable and has keyboard focus.  Think of a text field, when it doesn't have focus, it won't update.

Your second problem is using the `KeyBoardFocusManager`, which is simply overkill for this problem.

Instead, you should make use of the [Key Bindings] API, which is simpler the having to monitor the `KeyBoardFocusManager` and more robust then `KeyListeners`

Comment: this doesnt work, all the other parts of the programm will recongnize the if a key is pressed, but as soon as the run methode is called it doesnt work anymore

Comment: I now have the solution, i now use a new thread to run the run methode.

Comment: So now you're potentially violating the Event Diaoatching Thread