# KeyListener isn't working

Tags: java, swing, input, keylistener

I am working on a game and it was quite some time ago that I programmed in java so I have forgoten some things such as how to crate a KeyListener so I read the java docs and came up with this but it the player doesn't move when I press one of the keys.

Below is my code.

This is in the `Player.java` class (`Player.java` extends `Entity.java`):

(speed = 1)

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'W' | e.getKeyChar() == 'w' | e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            yPos = -speed;
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'S' | e.getKeyChar() == 's' | e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            yPos = speed;
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'A' | e.getKeyChar() == 'a' | e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            xPos = -speed;
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'D' | e.getKeyChar() == 'd' | e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            xPos = speed;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'W' | e.getKeyChar() == 'w' | e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            yPos = 0;
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'S' | e.getKeyChar() == 's' | e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            yPos = 0;
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'A' | e.getKeyChar() == 'a' | e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            xPos = 0;
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'D' | e.getKeyChar() == 'd' | e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            xPos = 0;
        }
    }
```

This is in the `Entity.java` class:

```
public void move(){
        x += xPos;
        y += yPos;
    }
```

This is in the `Entities.java` class:

```
KeyAdapter playerAdapter = new KeyAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            player.keyPressed(e);
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            player.keyReleased(e);
        }
    };

    public void move(){
        //Player
        player.move();
    }
```

and this is in the `Level.java` class (`Level.java` extends JComponent):

In the Level() method: `addKeyListener(entities.playerAdapter);`

In the paintComponent(Graphics g) method:

```
if(entities.player.getState())
 g2d.drawImage(entities.player.getImage(), entities.player.getX(), entities.player.getY(), this);
```

and int the run() method: `entities.move();`

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `getState()`?

Comment: @PM77-1 It check's if the player is alive or not

Comment: Does it return `true` in your testing?

Comment: yes it does, I have even tried to remove the if statement completly just to be sure

Comment: **What** are you adding your `KeyListener` to?  Does **it** have a focus?  See the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354230/keylistener-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Please note the following from the [docs for getKeyChar()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar%28%29):

> KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED events are not intended for reporting of
>   character input. Therefore, the values returned by this method are
>   guaranteed to be meaningful only for KEY_TYPED events.

For your purposes [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) suggests using [**key bindings**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html):

> To define special reactions to particular keys, use key bindings
>   instead of a key listener.