# KeyListener not work in object

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I got problem with KeyListener. I create class `gra` where is full code need to play game Tetris in constructor i only addKeyListener. In other class `Menu` I create object `Gra gra = new Gra()` and coll it when condition is met `gra.start(g);` but when I am in class `Gra` KeyListener not work. Please help me sove this issue.
He is code from class gra

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

//@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Gra extends JPanel implements KeyListener{


    public Gra(){
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        repaint();
    }
    public  void start(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.err.println("sdfafs");
        char c = arg0.getKeyChar();
        System.err.println(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        char c = arg0.getKeyChar();
        System.err.println(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        char c = arg0.getKeyChar();
        System.err.println(c);

    }

}
```

Comment: It's working fine with `setFocusable(true);` but focus can be lost at any time when its moved to other component.

Comment: use `mnemonics` (supported by all buttons and by tabbed panes as well as by JLabel) and `accelerators` (supported by menu items) instead of `KeyListener`

Comment: possible duplicate of [java keylistener not called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482268/java-keylistener-not-called) answered by me, or [this one answered by MadProgrammer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354230/keylistener-not-working). There are **lots** of duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 2):

`KeyListener` is very fickle. The component it is registered to must e focusable and have focus. There are many ways a component can loss focus or, depending on the system, not receive focus when requested.

Instead, use the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), as it will allow you to configure the focus level which will trigger the key events regardless