# I am trying to use KeyListener to move a rectangle but my inputs are not being read

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on this final project for my coding class, I want to make a simple video game but I am having issues with keyboard inputs. When I compile the code the frame is created and the rectangle is drawn but none of my keyboard inputs work.

```
public class GameProject extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    Timer tm = new Timer(5,this);
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
static int velX = 0;
int velY = 0;  

public void Game(){
    tm.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    x = x + velX;
    y = y + velY;
    repaint();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int c = e.getKeyCode();

    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        velX = -1;
        velY = 0;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        velX = 0;
        velY = -1;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        velX = 1;
        velY = 0;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        velX = 0;
        velY = 1;
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Game");
    GameProject game = new GameProject();
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(game);

}
```

}

Comment: Closed as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354230/keylistener-not-working). In the future, please use the search functionality of this site before asking questions that likely have been asked *many* times before. For instance, [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+keylistener+not+working) will get you many answers that are relevant to your problem.

Comment: [More search results where I answered a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+keylistener+not+working)